# Can any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be reached from 1 by doubling and summing digits?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f(n) = 2n$ and let $g(n)$ equal the digit sum (in base ten) of $n$.

Can any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be reached from $1$ after a finite series of applications of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Since $g(n)\equiv n\; mod(9)$ I don't think you can ever reach the number 9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither operation can ever produce a number divisible by $3$ from a number not divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain a bit about another answer given: The sum of digits of a number gives the same remainder when divided by $3$ as the number divided by $3$, and the reason why is that $999\ldots9$ is divisible by $3$ so $10^k$ always gives a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$ for any $k$. Thus if you add up the remainders from the digits, this is the same as calculating the remainder given the digits if you consider it to be a base-10 number.