# Is there a finite initial generating set for ${\mathbb N}$ given these two operations?

Tags: number-theory

This is inspired by [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415118/can-any-n-in-mathbbn-be-reached-from-1-by-doubling-and-summing-digits). Suppose we have $x_j \in \mathbb{N}$, and then we are allowed to perform any sequence of the following two operations: 1) Multiply by $k$ for some fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$. 2) Take the sum of digits in base $b$ representation for some fixed $b \in \mathbb{N}$. Obviously $k,b > 1$. Let $X_j$ be the set of all numbers that can be thus obtained with these operation starting with $x_j$. The question is, are there any universal fixed values for $k,b$ and finitely many $x_j$ so that the sets $X_j$ together cover all of $\mathbb{N}$?

As a follow-up, I thought of the following conjecture: If $gcd(b,k) = 1$ then it is always possible to find a solution of finitely many $x_j$. However I worry that I might be plunging too deep into murky waters of certain number theory with that one though...

Comment: From some numerical results, $x_j=1,3,9$ for $k=2$, $b=10$ looks promising.

Comment: @joriki Thank you, that is very interesting especially because in the original question the OP  simply asked if just starting at $x_1 = 1$ was enough, and it was commented that divisibility by 3 could  be achieved and divisibility by 9 could  be achieved, if and only if $x_1$ was divisible by 3 or 9 respectively. So your proposed 3 values of $x_j$ are definitely necessary. It would be great if they were sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $d=\gcd(b-1,k)>1$ and there is a finite cover.
The digit sum of $x$ is always $\equiv x\pmod{b-1}$.
Let $n$ be larger than all $x_j$ and not divisible by $d$.
Among the steps used to obtain $n$ from one of the $x_j$, there must be at least one increasing step, i.e., multiplication with $k$. But from then on our number remains a multiple of $d$, no matter which operation we apply. We conclude that $n$ cannot be reached, i.e., no such finite cover exists if $\gcd(b-1,k)>1$.

For the case $\gcd(b-1,k)=1$ I have no concrete idea, but I must say that the setup doesn't look much more tractable tan the $3n+1$ problem.

Comment: This is an insightful answer, thank you. I agree this problem looks a lot like what Erdos called "beyond current mathematics" like the $3n+1$ problem he was referring to, I just was very curious because in algebra for example we have the Hilbert basis theorem so I thought maybe if we allow arbitrary finitely many $x_j$ then this might help. Of course Hilbert basis theorem is way "cleaner" than this setup.